# wordpress json api phonegap handlebars custom_fields

Tags: wordpress, cordova, custom-fields, handlebars.js, json-api

I am using the "json-API" plugin for wordpress and I am trying to call that info into a phonegap app.

I am following a post on http://alexbachuk.com/wordpress-and-phonegap-part3/ and I am trying to find out how to call custom_fields in my content.

I have included the custom field like so: 
'http://www.example.com/?json=get_recent_posts&custom_fields=store-icon' in the ajax request.

the ajax request looks like this:

```
product: function(){
        function getProducts() {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://delectable.site40.net/blog/?json=get_recent_posts&custom_fields=store-icon',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var source   = $("#product-template").html();
                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    var blogData = template(data);
                    $('#product-data').html(blogData);
                    $('#product-data').trigger('create');
                    dfd.resolve(data);

                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return dfd.promise();
        };

        getProducts().then(function(data){
            $('#all-posts').on('click','li', function(e){                
                localStorage.setItem('postData', JSON.stringify(data.posts[$(this).index()]));
            });
        });


    }
```

and the template currently looks like this:

```
<script id="product-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" class="mainContent" data-theme="a" id="all-posts">

            {{#each posts}}

                <li class="center productss"><p class="photo circle center" style="margin-left: 31%;"><img src="{{thumbnail}}" width="85" height="57" /></ br><a data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide" href="single.html?{{@index}}"><h3 class="main_product">{{title}}</h3></a></ br><h5 class="left">R4200-00</h5><h5 class="right"><img src="{{custom_fields[0].url}}" width="150" height="20" /></h5></p></li>

            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </script>
```

how would I go about inserting that into my html. The alexbachuk.com post uses handlebars to parse the json so the post title is output as {{title}} and thumbnail as {{thumbnail}}. Is there a way to output custom_fields in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Use:

```
{{custom_fields.fieldname}}
```